# HTML expand div horizontally to fit children

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a horizontally scrolling web site.  There's a container div which I want to retain a fixed height but expand as required horizontally to fit the content inside it.  At the moment the div only expands horizontally as far as the page width.  There are actually 9 images to display but only the first 4 are shown.  See code and image below.  How do I make the container div expand horizontally to show all images please?

[image]

css:

```
body
{
    background-color:#dbdbdb; 
}

div.infinite-container
{
    background-color:#db0080; 
    height:180px;
}

img.infinite-item
{
width="320"; 
height="180";
margin-right:8px;
margin-bottom:8px;
display:inline-block;
}

.infinite-more-link 
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

PHP:

```
<div class="infinite-container">');


if ($num_results > 0)
{
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numImagesPerPage; $i++)
    {   
        $filePath = "animations/".$array[$i]['animationid'].".gif";
        echo('<img class="infinite-item" src="'.$filePath.'"/>');
    }
}    

echo('</div>');
```

This screenshot is after the changes below suggested by Andrei.  The pink area is the container div.  The images appear to break out below it.

[image]

Comment: Is this a writing mistake or intentional : `width="320"; height="180";` ?

Comment: should be `width:320px` and `height:180px` for sure :)

Comment: Why would you want the container to expand in such a fashion? I'd recommend a sort of carousel or ribbon instead of an indefinite expansion of space.

Comment: I know, just wanting to know if the OP knows too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, doing something like this should work:

```
body
{
    background-color:#dbdbdb;
    overflow:auto;
}
div.infinite-container
{
    background-color:#db0080; 
    height:180px;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

img.infinite-item
{
    width: 320px; 
    height: 180px;
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

jsFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6Abd/

What this does is:

- set the display mode to `inline-block` on the container. This way the container will be as large as needed to contain all items.
- set `overflow:auto` on `body` to show scroll-bars.
- correct the `width` and `height` of each item.
- add `white-space: nowrap;` to the container to force the items to stay on one line.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this thanks but it's still not displaying horizontally beyond the width of the page.  I've attached another photo to the original question.  Also, I don't know how many images I will need to display, it may be many more than 9, which is why I can't initially set the width of the container div.  Any thoughts please?

Comment: Updated my answer and added jsFiddle to prove it works. It was missing `white-space: nowrap;` from container. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, even though this answer is from 2 years ago the explanation really helped !  The fact that inline-block is necessary for the _container_ was a fact that eluded me in my searches

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS style :)

```
div.infinite-container
{
    width:2952px; /* (320 + 8) * 9 = 2952 */
}
```

But on the serious note - DIV shows (kind of) all your images, only images 5-9 are in next line and because container have fixed height, then they are hidden.

Comment: What if there are more items ? Since they are generated with a `for ($i = 0; $i < $numImagesPerPage; $i++)`

Comment: Sure this answer (first part) was kind of joke, but still author mention that `There are actually 9 images to display...` so, I can assume that `9` can be hard-coded.

Comment: `overflow:auto` and `display:inline-block` should do the trick in this case, but I'm not sure author wants exactly that. What's the point to extend container div outside of visible area on screen. Will this be some kind of "image slider" at the end?

Comment: I guess it will be, given the fact that from the image you can tell it can be a storybook of sorts.